# Protractor won't press buttons in Windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a series of protractor scripts that I've been running in Linux that work fine there for basic data input, button clicks, etc.  Using those same scripts in Windows with firefox, protractor simply skips clicking the buttons.    I have tried multiple ways to find the buttons (by.partialButtonText, by.css, etc) all of which work in Linux -- none of which work in Windows.  Protractor does not complain that it can't find the button or can't see the button -- it just doesn't click it.   I am using protractor 1.8.0 with firefox 31.2

I have now added Chrome and am running into similar issues.  I found some other users having similar problems, and they put in waits between finding the element and clicking it.  I can do that, but I don't understand why I should need to -- esp since that's not needed for Linux.

The button displays as:  + Add Image
It should open a modal for the user to interact with.

`<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" ng-click="imageEditMode=!imageEditMode"></button>`

The following selects all work in Linux, but not when I run the script on the same firefox version in Windows.

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.btn-primary', 'Add Image')).click();
element(by.cssContainingText('.btn-mini', 'Add Image')).click();
element(by.partialButtonText('Add Image').click();
```

Just to reiterate, I don't get an error about the Add Image button.   Protractor under Windows doesn't complain it can't find the element or that it isn't visible.  But it does not open the modal.

Comment: Could you supply some code?

Comment: I found the answer to this -- **protractor does not support IE9**.  I have upgraded the machine to IE10 and now the buttons are being pressed.